# Sliding a point along an edge?

Tags: modeling

I have a line with a point in the center (2 edges with 3 points that forms a straight line). How do I slide the middle point along the straight line it resides on?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Using [**Vertex Slide**](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/vertices.html#vertex-slide):

Select the point and press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> or <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>. Then move it to the desired point on the line with the mouse and click to set it. Hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> to slide it past the end of the edge.

Alternatively, this can be reached through the Edit Mode toolbar menus: *Vertex* -> *Slide Vertices*:

[image: Vertex -> Slide Vertices]

Or through the right-click context menu:

[image: Context menu -> Slide Vertices]

Comment: You can also enable Vertex Slide by pressing G twice

Comment: @Haunt_House great tip! That seems to work with edges too for edge slide.

Comment: It's also accessible with Ctrl+V > Vertex slide

Answer (score 12):

Just for the record, if you are using a very old version of blender that does not have vertex slide functionality:

1. Select one of the end vertices
2. <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>S</kbd> --> Cursor To Selected
3. Select the middle vertex
4. <kbd>.</kbd> (period) Set cursor as pivot point
5. <kbd>S</kbd> Now you can move the middle vertex along the line
6. When you are done, reset the pivot point with <kbd>,</kbd> (comma)

Answer (score 6):

Select the vertex and use <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>V</kbd> or <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> to move along the edge.

http://blenderbits.com/2013/09/02/blender-vertex-constraints-on-faces/