# Move vertices along an angle?

Tags: mesh

If I tap G twice I can move vertices along it's adjacent edges. Is there any way I can move it along a straight defined by the edges without changing the angle to the opposite edge? Just like that:

[image]

Comment: Try to press "control" button while you are moving the vertices.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, pressing C after GG may be what you're after. C disables clamping, meaning you can slide a vertex along its edges' general direction, to extend one of its edges. Try it out, and ping me if that's it. I'll happily add an answer about it, but at the moment I'm a bit busy.

Comment: [Description of _Vertex Slide_ in the Blender online manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/vertices.html?highlight=vertex%20slide#vertex-slide)

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3326/how-to-slide-some-vertices-along-a-slant-until-it-lines-up-vertically-with-anot and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2978/sliding-a-point-along-an-edge

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vertex slide past edge limit?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2981/vertex-slide-past-edge-limit)

Comment: +Mr Zak Indeed it is, the answer however doesn't work for me. GG, move cursor on desired axis, C did the trick, thanks to DuaneDibbley. I cannot access clamp settings with alt. I believe the answer is flawed but I will leave it to others to correct...

Comment: edge mode,oriental change to normal,then g the egde